# js - loop through sliced string and check entries in a database

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working in meteor and have a function that is passed a string argument. I want to see if that string exists in a mongo collection and if it doesnt start slicing the string to see if the string.length-1 exists, if not, then string.length-2 etc until all chars in the string are searched and return false if its not there.

I'm using an object size function to check if the object returned has any attributes (i.e. it was found in the db or not) but the code seems very ugly and computationally expensive in that I have to query the database str.length number of times, and then check to see if those entries exist...

so I have something like this:

```
checkString = function (str) {

    var result = myCollection.findOne({name: str});
    var result1 = myCollection.findOne({name: str.slice(0,(str.length - 1)});
    // ...

    if (Object.size(result) > 0) {
        return result;
    else if (Object.size(result1) > 0 {
        return result1;
    ...
    // this is getting messy already
}
```

How can I effectively loop through the str starting with its length in full and see if it exists, if it does then return the object, if it doesnt then keep checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i got your question right. This should solve your problem:

```
checkString = function(str) {
    for (i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
        var result = myCollection.findOne({
            name: str.slice(0, i)
        })
        if (result) {
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your search in a loop? Like this:

```
checkString = function(str)
{
 var result;
 for (loopIndex = 0; loopIndex <  str.length; loopIndex++)
 {
  if (loopIndex = 0)
  {
   //Takes the full string
   result = myCollection.findOne({name: str});
  } else {
   //Takes a smaller string
   result = myCollection.findOne({name: str.slice(0,(str.length - loopIndex)});
  }
  if (Object.size(result) > 0)
  {
   //Stop with looping because an entry has being found
   break;
  }
 }

 return result;
}
```

Note: Please, don't ask me question about meteor itself. For this case create new questions.

Comment: this was exactly the kind of thing I was after, but just couldnt join the dots in my head as to come up with it. no worries about the meteor side of things, thats cool. thanks for the code, much appreciated.